# if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}$ converges ($a_{n}$ are non negatives), study the convergence of the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\sqrt{\frac{a_{n}}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Does it converges? Or it depends on $a_{n}$ terms? I would thank to you if you can explain me if there are some cases in which the serie diverges and other in which the serie converges or if it just converges or if it just diverges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on $a_n$. For example, when $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, it converges; when $a_n=\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$ for $n\ge 2$, it diverges.

Comment: You might want to shift the argument of the logarithm in the second example a bit. As it stands $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Thank you. I correctly thougth that it depended on $a_{n}$ but I hadn't found any example which diverge. Thank you again

Comment: @Fabian: In the second example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: @Damaru: You are welcome!

Comment: @richard: last time I checked $\log 1=0$ such that $a_1$ is undefined.

Comment: @Fabian: That's why I wrote "for $n\ge 2$" in my answer.